# The relaxation method in the Linear and Integer Programming, some goniometric stuff

Tags: trigonometry, linear-programming, integer-programming, relaxations

I have a problem in a very nice book by Alexander Schrijver *Theory of Linear and Integer Programming* in the **Relaxation Method**.
Can some give me a hint how [here](https://books.google.cz/books?id=zEzW5mhppB8C&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=%22so+we+never+hit+a+solution+of+(36)%22&source=bl&ots=So0VBlSmSw&sig=ACfU3U32hcg1YVIkWF9Dfe-WT_BRM_TS3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUlqCpjIP6AhWJSPEDHaBWDEcQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22One%20easily%20checks%20that%22&f=false) on the page $160$ it was obtained the equation in this line: "...with $\rho ' > 0$ and $\varphi '=\pi+\psi+\arctan ((\lambda-1)\tan(\pi-\varphi+\psi))$" ? I believe that the formula $(22)$ on the page $157$ for $z^{k+1}$ has been used for this. [Here](http://62.182.86.140/main/769000/be4d2ced2c7df74909f7afafb3402b9d/%28Wiley-Interscience%20Series%20in%20Discrete%20Mathematics%20and%20Optimization%29%20Alexander%20Schrijver%20-%20Theory%20of%20Linear%20and%20Integer%20Programming%20%20-Wiley%20%281986%29.pdf) is the full book. The surrounding text is more or less clear to me.

[image]

[image]